# Do there exist two non-isomorphic embeddings of $K_4$ on the torus?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I found two embeddings with 2 faces (to make a torus in the end). One is obtained by gluing decagon and digon, the other – by octagon and square. How can I prove this strictly?

Comment: Is $K_4$ the Klein four-group? If so, what do you mean by embedding it in a torus? Can't you just choose any four points and assign them the group operation?

Could you also please explain what your embeddings are? I don't understand how you are using 12 squares.

Comment: @JosephCamacho $K_4$ is a complete graph

Comment: @JosephCamacho Since the tag is graph theory, I'd assume that K4 is the complete graph on 4 vertices, which indeed should have 2 faces if it is cellularly embedded on a torus. But what "gluing 10 and 2 squares" and "8 and 4 squares" means I do not understand either.

Comment: @RandyMarsh I’ve edited my question. Sorry for the original mistake

Comment: Are you asking how to prove that these gluings are embeddings of K4 (presumably you are talking about 2-cell embeddings) , or are you asking how to prove that they are not isomorphic? If it is the former, a simple picture of the gluing will do. If it's the latter, check for invariants (e.g. degrees of faces).

Comment: The former one. My general question is how to prove that there exist such embeddings